# ArgumentParser.add_argument: How to use action parameter with custom type parameter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse

When I try to do what question is about using:

```
parser.add_argument("--blah", type=func, help="Whatever", action='store_true')
```

...I get this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'type'
```

All I really want is to run a function named func (specified as argument type above) when this flag is used on commandline like so:

```
python3 script.py --blah
```

Is that possible somehow? Please let me know if I need to be more detailed with my question.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type It seems `action` and `type` are conflicting arguments to this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call your function after parsing arguments

`parser.add_argument("--blah", help="Whatever", action='store_true')`

`args = parser.parse_args()`

and then check for flag value and call function appropriately

```
if args.blah:
     func()
```

Answer (score 2):

The `type` parameter is meant to be a function that is tests and/or converts the commandline argument into something that will be stored in the `args` namespace.

```
parser.parse_args('--foo', type=int)  # default store action
```

will convert `['--foo','123']` into `Namespace(foo=123)`, as opposed to `foo='123'`.

But `action='store_true'` creates a True/False argument.  It doesn't take an argument after the flag.  So it's meaningless to give it a `type` parameter.    Admittedly the error message could be clearer, but this sort of error doesn't come up that often.  And it's a development problem, not a runtime one.

As others have pointed out, you can use the `True/False` value of `args.blah` to conditionally run your `func` after parsing.

When do you want `func` to be run?  After it's parsed all of the commandline?  Or while it is still parsing?  I prefer to separate parsing from running.  Use `argparse` to figure out what your user wants; use your own code to perform the action(s) after.

Comment: Thanks for such an insightful answer. As for the questions you asked -- I want to run `func` like so from command line: `python script.py --blah` i.e. after parsing is done.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do that:

```
from argparse import Action

class CleanUpAction(Action):
    '''
    @summary: Clean up the arguments
    '''

    def __call__(self, parser, args, values, option_string=None):
        if values.startswith('\'') and values.endswith('\''):
            values = values[1:-1]
        setattr(args, self.dest, values)

parser.add_argument('-blah', '--blah', type=str, action=CleanUpAction, help='clean up the argument')
```

This way it gets stored after the cleanup execution

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by clean up the arguments. Can you explain a bit?

Comment: that was just a sample function to demonstrate

Answer (score -1):

```
import argparse

def func():
    pass

def main(args):

    ############### Parsed command line arguments to initialize variables ######################

    blah = args.blah
    if blah:
        func()

def get_parser():

    ### Command line input parsing here. ###########
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='python ' + sys.argv[0], description='This program does blah!')
    parser.add_argument("-blah", , help='Run func',default= False, action='store_true')

if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = get_parser() 
    args = parser.parse_args()
```